# Как дать права пользователю на представление с вызовом функции в другой схеме?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Есть клиентское приложение, которое соединяется с БД (12c) всегда через пользователя `USER_SESSION`, и у него есть права на специальную ф-ию "авторизация" которая в случае успеха присваивает переменной `id_user` (сессионная переменная в ДРУГОМ пакете), к которому нет прав у `USER_SESSION` пользователя.

Есть следующее представление:

```
select * from xxx where id_user = root.core.GetIdUser;
```

Где: `root.core.GetIdUser` ф-ия для получения `id_user`. Сделано это для того, чтобы `USER_SESSION` мог выбрать только свои записи. Но я не могу дать права на это паредставление из-за того, что у `USER_SESSION` нет прав на `root.core`.

Как быть? Дать права на `root.core` не могу, так как тогда можно будет подделать `id_user`. Пароль от `USER_SESSION` теоретически не известен пользователю клиента, но можно вскрыть .exe, получить пароль и конектиться к БД через PL/SQL Developer.

Comment: я немножко запутался. А разве если у пользователя есть право вызвать пакет, то у него же нет возможности и поменять значение переменной в этом пакете перед вызовом `GetIdUser` ?

Comment: как альтернатива, вы можете попробовать настроить `oracle rls policy`. Хотя с  ними тоже куча мороки, но они точно обеспечивают безопасность того уровня, что вы хотите

Comment: Пакет вызывает вьюха а пользователь не может напрямую вызвать пакет.

Comment: на самом деле главный вопрос, который вам стоит себе задать. А вам вообще действительно нужна такая безопасность? вы ждете, что пользователи будут сами sql писать?

Comment: Если хоть один пользователь (а он всегда найдётся) начнёт сам "писать sql" то пострадают многие другие и не хотелось бы допускать такую возможность.

Comment: Тоже не совсем понял, в чём же проблема? Вы не хотите давать execute права пользователю на функцию, но хотите, чтобы он её всё таки запустил?

Comment: "но хотите, чтобы он её всё таки запустил?" - Я хочу что бы вьюха (select * from xxx where id_user = root.core.GetIdUser;) могла запустить ф-ию ! Вы не знаете что такое view? В общем я уже разобрался. Нужно было дать владельцу вьюхе права grant option на ф-ию.

Answer (score 2):

> но я не могу дать права на эту view из за того что у `USER_SESSION` нет прав на `root.core`

Не совсем так, даже если дать права `USER_SESSION` на `root.core`, то дать права на представлениие не получится. Попробуем на простом примере. Допустим, есть следующие пользователи с минимальными правами:

```
create user a identified by a
/
create user b identified by b
/
create user c identified by c
/
grant create session, create procedure to a;
grant create session, create view to b;
grant create session to c;
```

Пользователь A создаёт функцию и даёт права на выполнение B и C, а пользователь B создаёт представление:

```
conn a/a@&_connect_identifier

create function foo (c char) return char is begin return c; end;
/
grant execute on foo to b,c; 

conn b/b@&_connect_identifier
create or replace view bar as select a.foo ('bar') foo from dual;
```

Теперь, пользователь C может запустить функцию `foo`, но ещё не видит представление `bar`:

```
conn c/c@&_connect_identifier
select a.foo ('iam c') foo from dual;

FOO
-----------
iam c

select * from b.bar
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Пользователь B пробует дать права на представление пользователю C:

```
conn b/b@&_connect_identifier
grant select on bar to c;
grant select on bar to c
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01720: grant option does not exist for 'A.FOO'
```

Но он не может дать права на своё представление, которое содержит чужие объекты, даже  если пользователъ, которому выделяются парава, имет прямой доступ к этим чужим объектам.

Поэтому, сделаем теперь всё правильно, отзовём прямые права на `foo` у пользователя C, а дадим право пользователю B давать права на `foo` другим пользователям:

```
conn a/a@&_connect_identifier
revoke execute on foo to c;
grant execute on foo to b with grant option;

conn b/b@&_connect_identifier
grant select on bar to c;
```

В итоге, пользователь C может делать только то, что от него ожидалось:

```
conn c/c@&_connect_identifier
select a.foo ('iam c') foo from dual;
select a.foo ('iam c') foo from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "A"."FOO": invalid identifier

select * from b.bar;

FOO
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bar
```