# Ошибка при попытке выдать права на представление пользователю: "ORA-01720: Grant Option Does Not Exist"

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть представление:

```
select * 
from xxx 
where user_id = root.core.GetUserId() and account_id = root.core.GetAccountId();
```

но при попытке выдать права на представление пользователю `client` получаю ошибку:

> ORA-01720: Grant Option Does Not Exist

У `client` нет прав на схему `root` и на пакет `core`, и давать не хотелось бы.

Можно ли как-то не давая дополнительных прав избавиться от ошибки?

По идее, ему и не нужны прямые права, так как `root.core.GetUserId()` находится в представлении.

Comment: Вы уже задавали [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1026122) и вроде с ним рзобрались.

Comment: Точно) А я уже и забыл. Хорошо что в комментарии написал как решил.

Comment: Надо было не комментарий писать, а ответ. Может легче бы нашли сейчас.

Comment: А какая у вас версия? Вроде же в тексте ошибки должно покзывать, на какой объект опции не хватает.

Comment: Проблема в том что я думал что GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO владелец_view; будет достаточно и будут максимальные права.

Comment: all privileges - это системные привилегии, не путайте их с табличными.

Answer (score 3):

Какая причина возникновения ошибки:

> ORA-01720: Grant Option Does Not Exist

Посмотрим более детальное описание:

```
$ oerr ora 1720
```

> 01720, 00000, "grant option does not exist for '%s.%s'"
> **Cause**:  A grant was being performed on a view or a view was being replaced
> and the grant option was not present for an underlying object.
> **Action**: **Obtain the grant option on all underlying objects of the view** or
> revoke existing grants on the view.

Создатель представления должен иметь право, давать права на все объекты в представлении, другим пользователям. Это достигается коммандой [GRANT ... WITH GRANT OPTION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/GRANT.html#GUID-20B4E2C0-A7F8-4BC8-A5E8-BE61BDC41AC3):

> **WITH GRANT OPTION**
>
> Specify WITH GRANT OPTION to enable the grantee to grant the object privileges to other users and roles.

То есть, если B использует в представлении таблицу от A, то он должен получить от A разрешение давать пользоваться этой таблицей другим пользовтелям, даже если эти другие пользовтели уже имеют прямые права доступа к этой таблице. Короткий пример:

```
-- **А**
create table foo (val int)
/
grant select on foo to B with grant option; 

-- **B**
create view bar as select from a.foo
/
grant select on bar to someone;
```

[Подробный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1026122/217579) есть в ответе на связанный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно выдать права `grant EXECUTE ON ROOT.core to владелец_view WITH grant OPTION;`
И тогда если зайти под `client` view `select * from xxx where user_id = root.core.GetUserId() and account_id = root.core.GetAccountId();` будет работать а запрос `select root.core.GetUserId() from dual;` - не будет.